# Down sleeping bag with 200 g fill temperature ratings

Tags: gear, sleeping, temperature, down

The advertised down sleeping bag has fill: 200 g grey duck down 90/10.700 Cuin. Other material is 20D 380T nylon. Total weight is 630 g. Temperature ratings are 9°C, limit 4°C and extreme -9°C.

I don't know is that realistic temp rating that I could expect or is that too optimistic? Brand seems good. I(man) will be sleeping in 6-20 °C range from April till late October. Old synthetic bag ratings are 12/8/-4 °C and that is not enough.

Update: I can't believe insulation from only 200 g down fill is so good. I don't have experience with down so I can't say. I will buy it and see how it will work out.

Comment: 9 degrees is the confort rating. At 4 degrees (depending on how you sleep, but on average), you can expect to be able to sleep, but to be cold. (Assuming that's ISO ratings). That looks about right based on anecdotal evidence from my own bags.

Comment: However, do consider how much confidence you have in the expected temperatures: 6 degrees could be a bit cold, but easily manageable with keeping some more clothes on, but what happens if the temperature drops by a few more degrees that night? (Basically, do you already include a safety margin from the weather forecast, or is that the prediction verbatim?)

Comment: I think your answer is good and logical, nicely explained. I already ordered it, next week is testing!! Can't wait! Only 600 grams! I won't get into trouble because cold temperatures. I have survival foil with me all the time, used it quite a few times, know some tricks.